# Can I implement custom interfaces in a hibernate pojo?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, interface, pojo

Context: I'm using REST services and I need a service that after creating a record the result response of that service is a Json with the data that I have just inserted in the database, so as a design solution I created an interface to force all pojos to implement a method name "toHash" which basically deliver a HashMap with all the values of the pojo, then I've created a "Formatter" class, that I can use as an utility to deliver whichever format I want, like a JSON, and this class has a method named "JSon" receiving a HashMap as a parameter and returns a JSON with the content of this HashMap... so i can just call this utility from the service class and just output the Json with the result.

So I'm receiving an error, a mapping error, so I wondering, if it's a hibernate complain having a pojo implementing an interface which in hibernate world it means something related to the DB table.

This is the definition of my pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person implements Modelator {
```

And Modelator it's just a regular interface:

```
public interface Modelator {
    public HashMap<String,String> toHashMap();
}
```

I'm not attaching the stack trace error, because I just need to know, if it's possible to implement custom interfaces intended to handle the pojo to handle the output of the data of the pojo itself, thanks, for the help..

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: I did but receiving a mapping error, when i removed the implementation of the interface it builds ok...